# JSON Parsing without using URL to read json file in android

Tags: android, json

I am using url to take the file for parsing. Now i want read the file which is in sdcard for parsing.How can i do this?
here my code

reading file from url

```
    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/device1.json";
    JSONObject  json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            devices = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DEVICES);
```

now i want do this from reading the file in sdcard

```
    java.io.File device = new java.io.File("/mnt/sdcard/device1.json");
    FileReader device_Fr = new FileReader(device);
```

next how to pass this file for parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

read data from file into string & pass that to JSONObject.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String line, results = "";
    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null)
    {
        results += line;
    }
    reader.close();


JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(results);
```

Comment: sure lalit will take care from next time

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to read the json and store it in a string. Then parse it like this:

```
   String jsonStr = // read from file
    JSONObject  json = new JSONObject( jsonStr);
    // parse
　

　　devices = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DEVICES);
```